# Does Spring JDBC supports XA connection pools (for example, Oracle UCP)?

Tags: spring, jdbc, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, xa

I'd like to add XA connection pool to my Spring based application, specifically [Oracle UCP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJUCP/toc.htm). This pool works on XADataSource and XAConnection objects. Standard DataSource.getConnection(...) methods are not supported.

Trying working with that pool (that I am able to successfully set up in Spring) I am getting an error related to the fact that getConnection(...) methods invoked by JdbcTemplate are disabled and should not be used. I am just wondering whether any of Spring JDBC classes are able to work with XADataSource and XAConnections? Probably there are another ways to use Spring with XA connection pools? Will appreciate any advices on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for those who may experience similar problems - Spring doesn't support directly XA connection pools (through native `XADataSource.getXAConnection(...)` methods). You need to write a kind of wrapper utilizing `DatSource.getConnection(...)` methods.